# 2 additional partitions next to windows 8

Tags: windows-8, partitioning, disk-space, efi

so im trying to move my windows to different disk without harming them, and suddenly I found those two partitions in my disk:

[image: I highlighted two partitions that im not sure about]

Can I just delete them or are they something important?
from what I read on internet people say that its efi loader, is it true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the default recovery and uefi boot loader partitions for Windows. They were introduced in Windows 7. You can't remove them, sorry to say.

However, you don't have to display them as a drive letter, if you just don't want to see them.

Comment: You can remove them.  You just don't want to.

Answer (score 1):

If you looked in the [status column](http://support.moonpoint.com/hardware/pc/UEFI/Disk_Management.png) in the area above the portion of the Disk Management window you cropped, you likely would see them identified as a [recovery partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recovery_disc#Recovery_partitions) and [EFI System partition](http://support.moonpoint.com/hardware/pc/UEFI/efi_syspart.php). Regarding the EFI System Partition, the [EFI System Partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) Wikipedia article  notes:

> The EFI System partition (ESP) is a partition on a data storage device
>   that is used by computers adhering to the Unified Extensible Firmware
>   Interface (UEFI). When a computer is powered up and booted, UEFI
>   firmware loads files stored on the ESP to start installed operating
>   systems and various utilities. ... ESP contains the boot loader
>   programs for all installed operating systems (which are contained in
>   other partitions on the same or other storage device), device driver
>   files for devices present in a computer that are used by the firmware
>   at boot time, system utility programs that are intended to be run
>   before an operating system is booted, and data files such as error
>   logs. ... Microsoft recommends that when partitioning a disk, the EFI
>   System partition be the first partition on the disk. This is not a
>   requirement of the EFI specification itself.

Also, if you [perform a system image backup of a Windows 8 system](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/windows/win8/SysImage/), you would likely see the two partitions identified as "EFI System Partition" and "Recovery".